# Есть ли разница между итераторами конца для контейнеров одинакового типа?

Tags: c++, итераторы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли сравнивать итератор, относящийся к одному контейнеру с результатом, который возвращает метод `end()` другого контейнера, если контейнеры имеют одинаковый тип?

Что вообще означает `итератор конца`, который возвращается методом `end()`?

Comment: Нет, итераторы (даже `end()`), относящиеся к *разным* контейнерам, сравнивать нельзя. Кстати, как и указатели, относящиеся к разным массивам.

Comment: @Harry, что вообще собой представляет содержимое итератора, который возвращает метод `end()`?

Comment: Что собой представляет содержимое указателя, который указывает на элемент, следующий *за последним элементом* массива?... Примерно так и тут - его нельзя разыменовывать.

Comment: В `g++ (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0` для вектора `std::end()` адресует элемент непосредственно за последним. Это видно в выводе `printf("%p", &*std::end(v));`

Comment: Что касается сравнения, то для традиционных  машин, конечно можно. Напишите что-то типа `size_t p = (size_t)&*std::end(u), q = (size_t)&*std::end(v);` для векторов `v` и `u` и сравнивайте.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Итераторы, относящиеся к разным контейнерам (как и указатели, относящиеся к разным массивам) сравнивать между собой нельзя.

Итератор `end()` - это в определенном смысле абстракция, нечто, возвращаемое при применении операции перехода к следующему элементу к итератору, указывающему на последний элемент контейнера. Как указатель на элемент, следующий *за* последним элементом массива. Он вроде и есть, его можно сравнивать с другим указателем - но разыменовывать его категорически нельзя.

Как именно реализуется этот `end()` - это, насколько я помню, зависит от реализации.

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*